# Are pragma push/pop_macro directive stacks unique to each macro?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, preprocessor

Microsoft provides the [following example:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pop-macro?view=vs-2019)

```
// pragma_directives_pop_macro.cpp
// compile with: /W1
#include <stdio.h>
#define X 1
#define Y 2

int main() {
   printf("%d",X);
   printf(" %d",Y);
   #define Y 3   // C4005
   #pragma push_macro("Y")
   #pragma push_macro("X")
   printf(" %d",X);
   #define X 2   // C4005
   printf(" %d",X);
   #pragma pop_macro("X")
   printf(" %d",X);
   #pragma pop_macro("Y")
   printf(" %d",Y);
}
```

which outputs: 1 2 1 2 1 3

Is there a separate stack for macro "Y" and macro "X", or do they use the same stack for all macros?

Comment: Ah okay. I was confused by their wording which made it sound like there's a separate stack: "Saves the value of the *macro-name* macro on the top of the stack **for this macro**". I'm using macros because it's an embedded(aka memory limited) environment and they save space. Every byte counts, unfortunately :(

Comment: Macros do not save any space :). Macros are not even seen by the compiler. They are just (simplifying) text replacement.  Macros actually (same as inline functions) increase the FLASH consumption as the code is repeated many times.

Comment: When it comes to large macros for sure. I meant simple ones that act as constants, like `#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024`.

Comment: They do not have any impact on the code size or memory consumption. #defines are used to name constants and make one definition for the whole program. Then you need to change the value only in one place instead of many.

Comment: push and pop macro definitions it is something which should be avoided at any price

Comment: Yes, but a variable to hold buffer_size will necessarily have space in memory(e.g. 4 bytes), whereas text replacement would mean no space is taken up by said variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each macro has its own stack. As the documentation you link to says, [`push_macro`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/push-macro?view=vs-2019) “Saves the value of the *macro-name* macro on the top of the stack **for this macro**,” and [`pop_macro`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pop-macro?view=vs-2019) “Sets the value of the *macro-name* macro to the value on the top of the stack **for this macro**.”

We can confirm this interpretation with code that pops `X` and `Y` not in last-in-first-out-order yet recovers the values originally pushed for `X` and `Y` respectively:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    #define X "X0" 
    #define Y "Y0"
    printf("X=%s.\n", X);
    printf("Y=%s.\n", Y);
    #pragma push_macro("X")
    printf("Pushed X.\n");
    #pragma push_macro("Y")
    printf("Pushed Y.\n");
    #undef X
    #undef Y
    #define X "X1"
    #define Y "Y1"
    printf("X=%s.\n", X);
    printf("Y=%s.\n", Y);
    #pragma pop_macro("X")
    printf("Popped X.\n");
    #pragma pop_macro("Y")
    printf("Popped Y.\n");
    printf("X=%s.\n", X);
    printf("Y=%s.\n", Y);
}
```

[which prints](https://godbolt.org/z/4zPjzd):

```
X=X0.
Y=Y0.
Pushed X.
Pushed Y.
X=X1.
Y=Y1.
Popped X.
Popped Y.
X=X0.
Y=Y0.
```

Comment: Your example can be even more clear if you `print` between `pop_macro`'s, I think

Comment: Oh, sorry - I meant to print `X` and `Y` after `#pragma pop_macro("X")`, to see that `X` was pop'ed and `Y` - wasn't